# How to plot matrix with background color varying according to entry?

Tags: r, plot

I wanted to ask for any general idea about plotting this kind of plot in R which can compare for example the overlaps of different methods listed on the horizontal and vertical side of the plot? Any sample code or something

Many thanks [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrplot package and `corrplot` function in that package will create plots similar to what you show above, that may do what you want or give you a starting point.

If you want more control then you could plot the colors using the `image` function, then use the `text` function to add the numbers.  You can either create the margins large enough to place the text in the margins, see the `axis` function for the common way to add text labels in the margin.  Or you could leave enough space internally (maybe use `rasterImage` instead of `image`) and use `text` to do the labelling.  Look at the `xpd` argument to `par` if you want to add the lines and the `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` functions to help with the coordinates of the line segents.

Comment: Thank you, just the problem is the sample codes I could find are related to correlation matrix but my matrix is not like that. Do you have sample codes for non correlation matrix?

Answer (score 3):

A ggplot2-example:

```
# data generation
df <- matrix(runif(25), nrow = 5)
# bring data to long format
require(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df)
# plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfm, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks and do you know how can I add the margins? I mean I want to have on the top and left of the plot the names of methods i am comparing. How should ˜I add them?